# How can increase the file upload size in Moodle when I upload the Course file?

Tags: php, moodle

I am uploading a zip file there but it says `Error connecting to the server` and I have changed the php.ini memory_limit = 9024m

Comment: `memory_limit`? Didn't you mean `upload_max_filesize`?

Comment: I don't know but they show  ( Error connecting to the serve  )

Comment: Please share the full and exact error message. Probably you have to check your server's error log for this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a few places that might cause this upload issue.

I would suggest looking at your PHP.ini file to make sure that the setting there is correct.
Check the apache side as well.

With regards to increasing moodle upload sizes here is the doc: [Moodle Doc](https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/File_upload_size#Physical_access_to_Server)

Edit 1: Error connecting to server is the default Moodle error it prints when your upload file is either too big or takes too long to upload, thus your connection times out.

Comment: This does not look like an answer. Please explain further how looking at the configuration helps to resolve the problem